# Positive Lagrange multipliers of an equality constraint

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Consider the problem

\begin{align}
\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)\\
\text{subject to }\quad h(x) = 0\\
x\in X
\end{align}
where $X$ is a convex and compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I also know that the Jacobian $\nabla h(x)$ is full rank for all $x$, if that helps. Furthermore, we can assume $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and $h:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ are smooth functions.

Form the partial Lagrangian of the above as 
\begin{align}
L(x,\lambda) = f(x) - \lambda^\top h(x)
\end{align}

Using the sign convention of the above Lagrangian, under what conditions on $f$ and $h$ ensure that the vector of Lagrange multipliers, $\lambda$, is positive (that is, $\lambda_i>0$ for all $i$)? How can I show this mathematically?

---

**My attempt**: My thought process so far is that the Lagrange multipliers are set as to exactly ''cancel out the forces'' -- that is $\lambda$ is such that $\nabla f - \lambda^\top\nabla h = 0$. So, if I can show $\nabla f$ and $\nabla h$ are both acting in the same direction, then is $\lambda$ positive? (Update: I don't think this is right, due to the existence of the abstract set constraints $x\in X$ the gradient of the Lagrangian may never be zero)

---

**Update**: It is known (if we are *minimizing* $f$) that a necessary condition for $x^*$ to be a local minimum of the Lagrangian $M(x,\lambda) = f(x) + \lambda^\top h(x)$ over $x\in X$ (when $X$ is a convex set) is 
\begin{align}
(\nabla f(x^*) + \lambda^{*\top}\nabla h(x^*))^\top(x-x^*) \ge 0\quad \forall\, x\in X
\end{align}
This inequality can be thought of as the feasible variations at $x^*$ (the directions that point into the set $X$). I'm unsure how, or if, this is helpful.

---

**Update #2**: A useful direction may be the following. Write the constraints as $h(x) = a$. Let $x(a)$ be the minimizer for some $a$ and $\lambda(a)$ be the corresponding Lagrange multiplier (not sure how to show that this even exists, but that's besides the point for now). The objective value is $f(x(a))$. Now if I differentiate $f(x(a))$ with respect to $a_i$ I get the following
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f(x(a))}{\partial a_i} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial a_i}L(x(a),\lambda(a))\\
&= (\nabla f(x(a)) - \lambda(a)^\top\nabla h(x(a))\frac{\partial x(a)}{\partial a_i} - \frac{\partial \lambda(a)}{\partial a_i}(h(x(a)) - a) + \lambda_i(a)
\end{align}
but $h(x(a))=a$. So
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f(x(a))}{\partial a_i} = (\nabla f(x(a)) - \lambda(a)^\top\nabla h(x(a))\frac{\partial x(a)}{\partial a_i} + \lambda_i(a)
\end{align}
So, $\lambda_i(a) = \frac{\partial f(x(a))}{\partial a_i} - (\nabla f(x(a)) - \lambda(a)^\top\nabla h(x(a))\frac{\partial x(a)}{\partial a_i}$. So the Lagrange multipliers that we are after are evaluated at $a=0$. Where can I go from here? Have I messed up somewhere along the way -- it seems like this equation is not useful, as it depends on $\lambda(a)$ itself?

Comment: I doubt there is any useful nontrivial conditions. Notice that the multiplier is zero (or can select to be zero) if $x^*\in X$ is a local minimizer $f$ in the interior of $X$ without the constraints $h = 0$. So, if you don't want to rule out such cases, you won't have any useful conditions. Further, if you flip the sign of a constraint $h_i$, you also flip the sign of it's multiplier. So you have to rule that out too.

Comment: @user251257 Thanks a lot for the comment. I do know that the constraint $h(x)=0$ will always be present so we can rule out the first case you mentioned (as far as I understand). I'm also willing to keep the $h_i$'s defined as is (since, as you said, the sign of the multipliers will just flip if we flip the sign on $h$, so it will be the same conditions that will lead to a negative multiplier, in that case).